# How to access custom HTTP request headers on Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework, http-headers

I'm sending a post request to my API made using django rest framework:

```
curl --header "X-MyHeader: 123" --data "test=test" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update_log/
```

In my rest framework view, I want to get my costum header, and if the custom header satisfies a condition, I will proceed to analyze my post data.

Ok, my view looks like:

```
class PostUpdateLogView(APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (
        parsers.FormParser,
        parsers.MultiPartParser,
        parsers.JSONParser,
    )  

    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)

    def post(self, request):
        print request.Meta
        # Get custom header
        # Validate custom header
        # Proceed to analize post data

        # Make response
        content = {
            'response': 'response',
        }

        return Response(content)
```

I'm trying to find my custom header on request.Meta element, but when I print request.Meta, I get a 500 error. If I print request.data, I get the expected response.

¿What is the way to get a custom header on my post request using django rest framework?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The name of the meta data attribute of request is in upper case:

```
print request.META
```

If your header is called "My-Header", your header will be available as:

```
request.META['HTTP_MY_HEADER']
```

Or:

```
request.META.get('HTTP_MY_HEADER') # return `None` if no such header
```

[Quote from the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META):

> HTTP headers in the request are converted to `META` keys by converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores and adding an `HTTP_` prefix to the name. So, for example, a header called `X-Bender` would be mapped to the `META` key `HTTP_X_BENDER`.

Comment: I'm sorry, like a missing (;), I was two hours on this... Maybe, do you know how can see the bug detail when I request the api using curl? when i send the post request using curl, i only can see on my console the answer like [05/Feb/2015 08:40:39] "POST /api/update_log/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78112, but I can't see the bug detail. Thank you and excuse my carelessness.

Comment: Redirect the output of the `curl` to the file and then open this file in the browser.  `curl ... http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update_log/ > error.html`

Answer (score 19):

Seeing this is an old post, I thought I would share the newer and more flexible approach that is available since Django 2.2. You can use the [request's headers object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.headers):

```py
# curl --header "X-MyHeader: 123" --data "test=test" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update_log/

request.headers['X-MYHEADER']       # returns "123"
request.headers['x-myheader']       # case-insensitive, returns the same
request.headers.get('x-myheader')   # returns None if header doesn't exist

# standard headers are also available here
request.headers.get('Content-Type') # returns "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

The biggest differences with `request.META` are that `request.headers` doesn't prepend headers with `HTTP_`, it doesn't transform the header names to `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` and that the headers can be accessed case-insensitively. It will only transform the header to `Title-Casing` (e.g. `X-Myheader`) when displayed.

Answer (score 12):

If you provide a valid header information and get that information from backend then follow those

```
client-name='ABCKD'
```

then you have get that client information in post or get function following this-

```
request.META['HTTP_CLIENT_NAME']
```

it will give you output 'ABCKD'.

remember that, whatever the valid variable name you provide in your header information in request, django convert it uppercase and prefix with '`HTTP_`'
in here it will client-name converted to `CLIENT_NAME` and prefix with `HTTP_`.
so final output is HTTP_CLIENT_NAME