# How do you use the django rest framework serializer to populate a reverse relationship in a m2m mapping?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here's what I have

```
class Component(models.Model):
    risks = models.ManyToManyField(Risk)
    ...

class Risk(models.Model):
    label = models.TextField()
    ...

class RiskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    severity = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Severity.objects.all(), slug_field='label')

    class Meta:
        model = Risk
        fields = [
            'id',
            'label',
            'severity',
            ...

        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print('foo', validated_data)
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        if self.context.get('component_id'):
            component = Component.objects.get(id=self.context.get('component_id'))
            component.risks.add(instance)

        return instance
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is I'm trying to create a new Risk using the serializer for an existing component object. Like so:

```
    risk = RiskSerializer(data={
        'label': 'foo bar'
        ...
    }, context={'component_id': component.id})
    risk.is_valid()
    risk = risk.save()
```

The idea is that if I can pass the component_id then I could override the create method to somehow find and the component object, create it, and then add it to it.

What's the correct way to populate Component's risk m2m field?

Comment: your `Risk` model doesn't have a foreign key to `Component` Model

Comment: It doesn't @EbrahimKarimi it uses the reverse relational mapping from the Component model.

Comment: please let me know if i understood correctly, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018110/drf-how-to-save-a-model-with-a-foreign-key-to-the-user-object)

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi unfortunately no, that doesn't address the concerns I have

Comment: would you please edit your question with better explanation?

Comment: you shouldn't override `create` method anyway, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853588/django-rest-framework-create-object-with-relationship-many-to-many)

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi the linked answer appears to suggest that we should be overriding the `create` method.

Comment: yes sorry i was wrong